# Why does Python 3 json.loads("foo.com") not work yet json.loads("123.6") does?

Tags: json, python-3.x

When I try to load "foo.com" I get an exception, as expected; however, if I am loading a string containing a float number, it works. Just trying to figure out why this is the case.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:13:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> j = json.loads("foo.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>> j = json.loads("123.6")
>>>
```

Comment: Because `123.6` is valid JSON, but `foo.com` (without quotes!) is not?

Comment: @ForceBru Both are quoted, therefore both should be strings.

Comment: @DeepSpace, because the grammar doesn't allow it: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2

Comment: @FranzKafka, they're strings for Python, but not the JSON parser.

Comment: `123.6` is a valid number literal, `"foo.com"` is a valid string literal, but `foo.com` isn't valid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from RFC7159 that defines JSON:

> These are the six structural characters:
>
> ```
>  begin-array     = ws %x5B ws  ; [ left square bracket
>  begin-object    = ws %x7B ws  ; { left curly bracket
>  end-array       = ws %x5D ws  ; ] right square bracket
>  end-object      = ws %x7D ws  ; } right curly bracket
>  name-separator  = ws %x3A ws  ; : colon
>  value-separator = ws %x2C ws  ; , comma
> ```
>
> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
>      the following three literal names:
>
> ```
> false null true
> ```
>
> <...> No other literal names are allowed.
>
> ```
> value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string
> object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
>            end-object
> array = begin-array [ value *( value-separator value ) ] end-array
> number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]
> string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
> ```

As you can see, the input `foo.com` does not satisfy any of that:

- it doesn't start with a `begin-object`
- nor does it start with a `begin-array`
- nor is it a number
- nor is it a string, because it *does not* start with a `quotation-mark`

However, `123.6` is a number:

```
123 . 6 == int frac
```

where, as per the RFC:

```
frac = decimal-point 1*DIGIT
int = zero / ( digit1-9 *DIGIT )
```

Thus, `123 . 6` is a `value`, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

`json.loads` expects a string. When the JSON parser handles this string all is left is `foo.com` which is an invalid token. It's an edge case of this example:

```
json.loads('{a: 1}')
```

You would not expect this to work, wouldn't you? `a` is an invalid token.

For this to work we will need another set of quotes:

```
print(json.loads('"foo.com"'))
# foo.com
```